# Sharing configuration (.*rc files) between a normal user account and root

Tags: linux, fedora, root, privileges

On a Fedora Core box, I have a normal non-privileged user and I also have sole access to the root account. Because I am the only administrator of this box, I frequently *su* over to root for administrative tasks. The problem is that many of the user configuration I've become accustomed to are only configured on my day-to-day account (*.vimrc*, *.bashrc*, *.screenrc*, etc).

Other than giving my day-to-day user account privileges to perform administration tasks, how would I go about sharing configuration between these two accounts? Any suggestions and/or best practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify settings in the `sudoers` file (`visudo`) to carry environment settings forward to the privileged environment. See `man sudoers` and look for settings that have "env" in their names.